# Excel 2016 how to autofill data entries based on a reference sheet

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel document where I input monthly sales to analyze via pivot tables and graphs. The software I export sales data from exports it in the following way:

MONTH | PRODUCT ID | PRODUCT NAME | SALES REP | QUANTITY | VALUE |

However, I need two more categories which the software does not export and are therefore empty when I paste new data:

MONTH | PROD. ID | PROD. NAME | SALES REP | QUANTITY | VALUE | CATEGORY | BRAND

Currently, I input them manually by dragging down. As there are thousands of rows to input monthly, this is getting more and more time consuming. I want to create a sort of "reference sheet" and then use that so that whenever I paste rows with products' names and IDs, the Category and Brand columns will be autofilled with the information I have given in the reference sheet. This sheet would have the following heading for all the products:

PRODUCT ID | PRODUCT NAME | CATEGORY | BRAND

How would the code for this look? Any help would be great since I am new to VBA.

[Pivot table's data source before the two categories are manually inputted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJgY8.png)

[Reference sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEgnn.png)

Comment: You can use FORMULA to return value directly, you can use **SUMPRODUCT** function: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function

Comment: have a look into "using index match in excel" . | And share us, your tried formula.. or where you're stuck (with the tries)